# Armor Stand with lying pose

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to do an Armor Stand with a lying down pose, however, everytime I tried to do this, the leg of the Armor Stand will be detached from its body, which looks a bit creepy and weird; this is how it looks:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with this command?

```
 /entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,r=5] {ShowArms:1,NoBasePlate:1,NoGravity:1,Pose:{LeftLeg:[90f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[90f,0f,0f],Body:[90f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[90f,0f,0f],RightArm:[90f,0f,0f],Head:[90f,0f,0f]}}
```

I want an Armor Stand lying down with its leg connected with its body; how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done with a single ArmorStand. All of the limbs pivot around pre-determined points; you can see this more easily with an [ArmorStand positioning tool](http://haselkern.github.io/Minecraft-ArmorStand/).

You could however position two ArmorStands in a way such that the legs of one are paired with the body/arms of another, like this:

**ArmorStand for body:**

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~1 {NoBasePlate:1b,ShowArms:1b,Pose:{Body:[278f,0f,0f],Head:[317f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[270f,0f,0f],RightArm:[270f,0f,0f]}}
```

**ArmorStand for legs:**

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~2 {NoBasePlate:1b,Pose:{Body:[180f,0f,0f],LeftLeg:[270f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[270f,0f,0f]}}
```

[image: 2 ArmorStands]

Dress them up, give `Invisible:1b` and `NoGravity:1b` to them, and then use `/tp` to teleport them into place:

[image: 2 ArmorStand positioned to look like a zombie lying down]

Answer (score 1):

the code is:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoBasePlate:1b,ShowArms:1b,Rotation:[192f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{id:"chain",Count:1b},{id:"slime_block",Count:1b}],HandItems:[{id:"oak_fence",Count:1b},{}],CustomName:"robot minion",Pose:{Body:[91f,0f,0f],Head:[91f,0f,186f],LeftArm:[91f,0f,0f],RightArm:[91f,4f,0f]}}
```

But first make a 3 by 3 slab area under the middle slab and place a command block then summon it and bingo